# css in ionic and phonegap with boxes

Tags: html, ios, css, angularjs, cordova

I'm making a little quiz in ionic and im dynamically creating the boxes using n-g repeat for the answers. Ive bee trying for hours but it either works well on ipad but aweful on iphone or the other way round. Here is how it looks on my phone :

[image]

and here on my ipad
[image]

All im trying to do is have an object with an answer so for example "over the mood" and dynamically create the boxes that corespond with the answer so for this example [][][][] [][][] [][][][]..

I am using ng-repeat to do what i have in my example :

```
<form>
<span ng-repeat="content in answerArr track by $index" class="single-input"><span style="margin-right:10px;"></span><!--this adds space -->
<div class="testingg" style="width:50%;margin-right:auto;">
<div style="width:50%;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;">
<span class="single-input" ng-repeat="contentt in content track by $index">

<div class="row"style="">
          <span ng-if="$index < content.length">
              <div class="box single-number" style="">
                    <input type="text" class="" focus maxlength="1">
               </div>
           </span>
           </div>
</div>
</span>
</div>
</span>
</form>
```

is there a better way to do this or am i missing something obvious? im trying to achieve the sort of centered css where if the word overlaps then it goes to the next line .. something like the below

[image]

althought they use __ and i am using a box. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can Set particular length for your each rows .And Using answer's length create substrings of tho and push them into any object.Like if your row's length is 5 and your answer is "over the mood" . You have to create 3 substrings
and push them into object . Now implement an nested ng-repeat, first with 
that object containing substring and then inside that with substring itself
Hope It will help you :)

Comment: thats what im doing i have an object with 3 objects inside, each with an array for each letter so like [[o][v][e][r],[t][h][e],[m][o][o][d]]